# Arangodb installation on ArchLinux

Tags: linux, installation, cmake, arangodb, archlinux

**OS** : ArchLinux 
**Source** : https://github.com/sleepycat/arangodb_arch
**arangodb version** : 3.6.3

what I did

```
git clone https://github.com/sleepycat/arangodb_arch.git
cd arangodb_arch
makepkg 
# or assuming you have a gpg key:
makepkg --sign
```

After it passes tests successfully installation fails with this error

```
==> Entering fakeroot environment...
==> Starting package()...
    -> Preparing ArangoDB.
install: invalid user ‘arangodb’
==> ERROR: A failure occurred in package().
Aborting...
```

I thought this error may be related to arangodb-users.conf -->

```
u arangodb - "ArangoDB system user"
```

I tried to change the user and username but It raises new Error on validating source

```
==> ERROR: One or more files did not pass the validity check!
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

so after lots of searches, this is what you should do for installing Arangodb on ArchLinux

before installation

```
sudo useradd -r arangodb
```

installation

```
yay -S arangodb
```

after installation

1. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
2. sudo systemctl enable arangodb3.service
3. sudo systemctl start arangodb3.service
4. /etc/arangodb3/arangosh.conf => authentication = false
5. /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf => authentication = false
6. Then set the passwords and create the root user

```
arangosh
require("org/arangodb/users").update("root", "mypassword")
```

7. /etc/arangodb3/arangosh.conf => authentication = true
8. /etc/arangodb3/arangod.conf => authentication = true
9. sudo systemctl restart arangodb3.service